# Sublime Text и padding

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Когда я начинаю писать в CSS `p`, Sublime Text 3 вместо `padding:` предлагает написать `padding-top:`, `padding-left:`. И только когда я пишу `pad`, мне предлагается `padding:`.

У меня установлен Emmet. Ввожу `p`, нажимаю <kbd>tab</kbd> — выдаётся `padding-right: ;` пишу `p-` — `padding-right: ;`.

Что мне сделать, чтоб в Sublime Text мне предлагалось `padding: ;`?

Comment: В [официальной документации Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) `p` → `padding: ;`, у меня всё в порядке. И в выпадающем меню мне первым делом также [выдаётся `padding:`](https://i.gyazo.com/106a928312db699e02ba42593f147cb6.png). Спасибо.

Comment: ну, я рада, что у Вас все ок. Мне надо было скриншоты предоставить, что у меня padding-right: выпадал?

Comment: Нет, я к тому, что по умолчанию так не происходит, автокомплит должен корректно работать без подобных изменений настроек. Возможно, у Вас установлены конфликтующие с Emmet плагины, в которых и следует искать проблему. Простите, если дал неправильно себя понять. Спасибо.

Comment: Удалять другие плагины, чтобы найти конфликтный - это не вариант. Все установленные плагины мне нужны.

Comment: Webfeya, это единичный случай, когда приходилось самостоятельно прописывать автокомплиты, или ещё приходилось? Спасибо.

Comment: Приходилось. Background:linear-gradient тоже отсутствует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже сама нашла решиение:

Ctrl+Shift+P, Bro, Enter

В папке User создаем файл CSS.sublime-completions со следующим содержимым:

```
{
    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "p", "contents": "padding:" }
    ]
}
```

Перезапустить Sublime Text.

Comment: Ещё вариант, если проблемы с Эмметом и автокомплитами — установить сниппеты для [HTML](https://github.com/joshnh/HTML-Snippets) и [CSS](https://github.com/joshnh/CSS-Snippets). В файл пользовательских настроек Emmet добавить `"disabled_single_snippets": "fig meta nav ol script style ul"`. Спасибо.